# Trying to get the version of Maven from inside a plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a Maven plugin, and I need to know the version of Maven that's actually running, from within the code of the plugin. The expected result would be the version number (e.g. **3.3.9**) after running **mvn -version** in the shell, like so:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.12.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Since the Maven documentation is somewhat lacking, and Googling "Maven version" only brings me results about the version of the projects (as opposed to the version of Apache Maven itself), it's hard to come by an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Maven 3.0.2, you can use the [`RuntimeInformation`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/rtinfo/RuntimeInformation.html) component, which provides information about the current Maven runtime environment.

```
@Component
private RuntimeInformation runtimeInformation;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    String mavenVersion = runtimeInformation.getMavenVersion();
    getLog().info(mavenVersion); // prints 3.3.9 when running the build with that version
}
```

The method [`getMavenVersion()`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/rtinfo/RuntimeInformation.html#getMavenVersion()) returns exactly the current Maven version, without the need to parse anything:

> Retrieves the current Maven version, for example "3.0.2".

The Mojo will need to have a dependency on `maven-core` to be able to locate that class:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version> <!-- or some other version, like 3.3.9 -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just what I have been searching for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user property `maven.build.version` as following :

```
public class Plugin extends AbstractMojo {

  @Parameter(defaultValue = "${maven.build.version}")
  private String mavenVersion;

  ...

}
```

The property will contain the following value in your case :

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T18:41:47+02:00)
```

This is not exactly what you were expecting but I hope this will help you.

Comment: Also a good answer, although @Tunaki 's answer is spot on. Thanks!